# Append bunch of items into collection stored in Memcached

Tags: c#, caching, memcached, enyim.caching

It's possible to store a list of items in Memcached but in my case I need to have an ability to append data to the existing collection that is already stored in Memcached.
Since collection is too large (>10 Gb) the way to retrieve/append and then rewrite entire collection does not suit.
After some investigation I chose `Enyim.Caching` library as a client to interact with Memcached.
How such appending can be achieved?

Or you might advice me totally another option how to store large data in Memcached.